# UIImages losing dimensions and getting bigger in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am using `xcode` with `Swift` to develop a very simple application that should only run on iphone7. I have a bunch of `UIImages` and `UIButtons with images` in my application and I have received a bunch of PNGs to use in the application.

They are named more or less image1.png, image2.png and so on.
If I check the dimension of the PNGs, they look right to me.

For example one background image has the following dimensions: `750 x 1335`.
Once I add this PNG to my application, and add it to the story board, the image looks huge.
I need to manually enter the following dimensions `350 x 887` (which is half the size)  in order to get the image to fit the size of the phone on the screen.

I have no idea what is going on here! It is something I am doing wrong or it there something wrong with the exported PNGs?

Comment: How are your images named? Do you have separate versions for 1x and 2x or do you just have images named like image1.png and image2.png? If you have different versions for 1x, 2x, and 3x etc. the images would be named image1.png, image1@2x.png, and image1@3x.png etc.

Comment: I just have one image, more like image1.png and so on.

Comment: can show code where are you setting image , try to set imageview property scaletoaspectfit

Comment: If you can post a screenshot showing how the image looks huge - it might help in identifying whether it is because the image is scaled too big or because you added it at native size and it is too big for the screen at that size ...

Comment: I am not using code, just adding them by drag and dropping UIImage into the Story Board.

Comment: pls check Clip To Bounds in Drawing options

Answer (score 0):

iPhone's physical screen resolution is rarely referenced as is, instead it is calculated in points. On the early iPhones 1 point was actually 1 pixel. On modern iPhones 1 point is actually representing 2x2 pixels, or sometimes 3x3 pixels (for Plus models). To make it all work, all the graphics for UI elements (buttons and the like) are provided in two or three resolutions:

- for the case where 1point = 1pixel
  in such case the image name is not postfixed with anything (`image1.png`)
- for the case where 1point = 2x2pixels
  in this case the image name is postfixed with @2x (`image1@2x.png`)
- for the case where 1point = 3x3pixels
  in this case the image name is postfixed with @3x (`image1@3x.png`)

You have two ways of managing this.
**First goes like this**:

1. Rename all of your images, so that they all have @2x.png at the end. Like this:
   `image1.png   becomes   image1@2x.png`
   `image2.png   becomes   image2@2x.png`
2. Drag all those images to your `Assets.xcassets` folder in XCode:
   [image]
3. Now you can assign the images to buttons, backgrounds, and pretty much anything else by calling its name (omitting the @2x at the end), like this:  `image1`, `image2`, etc. The resolution will fit now.
   You can also choose the images in drop-down lists in your Storyboard to apply them to different elements (like said buttons).

**Second way is similar**.
You don't rename the images, and drag them into the `Assets.xcassets` folder just as they are. Then you manually drag the thumbnails of your images into 2x slots. Here's an example with an image called 'gear':
[image]

For more information on how physical screen resolution of the iOS devices differs from its internal representation (which is in points), refer to this handy guide:  https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

I think you content mode is not right. This is how to fix it:

[image]

1. Click to your UIImageView
2. Look at the right hand side and choose `View` -> `Content Mode` to `Aspect Fit`

This is the document about `content mode` of a Image View
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/

I hope it can help you